# Estimating Congestion Window Sizes in Python using DPKT from pcap file

Tags: python, tcp, congestion-control, dpkt

I am currently completing an assignment for a Networking course related to parsing PCAP files and outputting some information about the TCP flows. I have pretty much finished but I've been stuck on one part for days. This part of the assignment requires us to estimate the first 3 congestion window sizes in a flow (estimated at the sender) and to comment on how the congestion window size grows. Currently, the congestion window has been described to me as the number of packets sent in one RTT. From this information, I attempted to count the number of transactions from sender to receiver and add it to a list whenever a response was received from the receiver. Though, I seem to be getting a ton of different values even though it seems like I should only be getting a few. Is there anything I'm missing? Any advice or information on how to estimate congestion window sizes in a flow using DPKT in Python 3 would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what does it mean - first 3? as long as congestion window is smaller than BDP, i.e., acks do not come before the whole window is set, you can take first packet, then count all packets sent before first ack is received. when first ack is received, you start second rtt, and count all packets sent before the ack for the first packet of second rtt is received

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Effie thank you, this was my original understanding but our professor decided not to use this procedure for the assignment and instead for us to choose a static RTT time without evaluating ack's.